# RXJS5 Queue some stream until event then process normally

Tags: node.js, rxjs, rxjs5

I am processing data from GDAX's websocket that emits the status of trades in real time (Source B).  In order to build a complete order book I need to get a current snapshot of the book through an API call (Source A).

First I process Source A which contains a sequence number, while I am processing this I am queueing events from Source B.  Once Source A is processed I emit a "SYNCED" status, when SYNCED is received I release all of the queued events from B as an array and discard any that are prior to the sequence number from Source A and then processes them.  At the point that the queued events are released any incoming events from B should be processed in real time.

[image]

Source B can drop an event at any point, and when that happens I reset the state to blank, call Source A and repeat the process.

Right now, I am trying to use the buffer in RXJS, but it just releases the events from before SYNCED is emitted, and then starts to buffer B until the event is called again.  This is different because I only want to queue events while the sync is in process and then once it is done, I want to process the backpressured events and then process the events as they come in.  I am not really sure how to accomplish this in terms of observables... Here is what I have so far:

```
Observable
  .fromEvent(this.ws$, 'message')
  .map((m: any) => m.data)
  .map((s: string) => JSON.parse(s))
  .buffer(process$)
  .flatMap(_ => _)
  .filter((message: any) => message.sequence > this.sequence)
  .subscribe((message: any) => {
    if (message.sequence !== this.sequence + 1) {
      throw new Error("Out of sync");
    }
    this.sequence = message.sequence;
    this.emit('message', message);
  }, (err: any) => {
    throw new Error(err);
  });
```